# Como le puedo hacer para que el primer resultado lo pueda reocupar si le digo que si quiero continuar haciendo operaciones?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double res = 0;
    String operacion;
    boolean comprobar = false;


    do{
        String numero1;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n Ingrese un digito. ");
            numero1 = sc.nextLine();
        } while (!numero1.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
        double nume1 = Double.parseDouble(numero1);
        double n1 = new Double(numero1);


        do {
            System.out.println("\n ¿Que operación desea hacer? (Solo coloque un signo)");
            System.out.println("Teniendo en cuenta que: \n + = sumar \n - = restar \n"
                    + " x = multiplicar \n / = dividir \n * = elevar primer número al segundo numero."
                    + "\n % = residuo");
        operacion = sc.nextLine();
            if (operacion.equals("+") || operacion.equals("-") || operacion.equals("x") ||
                operacion.equals("X") || operacion.equals("/") || operacion.equals("%") ||
                operacion.equals("*")) {
                comprobar = true;
            }else { comprobar = false; }
        } while (comprobar != true);

        String numero2;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n Ingrese otro signo.");
            numero2 = sc.nextLine();
        } while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
        double nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
        double n2 = new Double(numero2);

        do{
            comprobar = true;
            switch(operacion){
                case "+":
                    res = n1 + n2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    res = n1 - n2;
                    break;
                case "x":
                case "X":
                    res = n1 * n2;
                    break;
                case "/":

                    while(n2 == 0){
                             do {
                                System.err.println(" En el denominador se encuentra \n"
                                        + "un cero, para evitar errores coloca otro número.");
                                numero2 = sc.nextLine();
                            }while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
                                nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
                                n2 = new Double(numero2);
                    }
                    res = n1 / n2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    res = Math.pow(n1, n2);
                    break;
                case "%":
                    while(n2 == 0){
                             do {
                                System.err.println(" En el denominador se encuentra \n"
                                        + "un cero, para evitar errores coloca otro número.");
                                numero2 = sc.nextLine();
                            }while (!numero2.matches("[+-]?[\\d]*[.]?[\\d]+"));
                                nume2 = Double.parseDouble(numero2);
                                n2 = new Double(numero2);
                    }
                    res = n1 % n2;
                    break;
            }
        }while(comprobar != true);

        System.out.println("(" + numero1 + ") " + operacion + " (" + numero2 + ")" + " = " + res);
        System.out.println("\n ¿Desea hacer alguna otra operación? \n");
        System.out.println(" [s/n]");
        do{
            comprobar = true;
            operacion = sc.nextLine();

            switch (operacion) {
                case "s":
                case "S":
                case "n":
                case "N":
                    break;
                default:
                    System.err.println("\n Error, ponga un literal valido. \n");
                    comprobar = false;
            }
        }while(comprobar != true);
    }while(operacion.equals("s") || operacion.equals("S"));
```

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que el resultado de la operación que queres recuperar sería la variable res.
Si es así, podes probar usando una lista al principio del programa:

```
List<Double> resultados = new ArrayList<>();
```

y en cada iteración agregas un:

```
resultados.add(resultado);
```

entonces podes recuperar cada resultado que guardaste en orden.